# XPath: can I use for-return with if-then-else?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have an XML document with a collection of nodes:

```
<doc>
    <product>
        <name>one
        </name>
        <price>21
        </price>
        <category>cat1
        </category>
        <id>1
        </id>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>two
        </name>
        <category>cat2
        </category>
        <price>19
        </price>
        <id>2
        </id>
    </product>
</doc>
```

And I need to select the *name* of the product if the price is > 20 and category is cat1, and the *id* of the product otherwise.

What i tried to do was to iterate through the nodes and return name or id depending on the above criteria:

```
for $product in /doc return if (price > 20 and cat = 'cat1') then name else id
```

But I get the error "Expecting return, but found if(".

Can I not use `if` in `for`'s return clause?

Comment: What language is that? (It's not XPath) You should tag your question.

Comment: Works fine for me. Except you actually need to access the variable, to get a result. `for $product in /doc/product return if ($product/price > 20 and $product/category = 'cat1') then $product/name else $product/id` . But it is nicer without for loop `/doc/product/if (price > 20 and category = 'cat1') then name else id`

Comment: @Fratyx it is indeed XPath - XPath 2.0 to be precise.

Comment: @BeniBela, don't you need parenthesis around the `if` expression, as in `/doc/product/(if (price > 20 and category = 'cat1') then name else id)
`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: I actually do not in my implementation. Now is that a bug or a feature?

Comment: @MichaelKay Okay sorry. Propably I'm too old

Comment: Also note that, given that indentation, you don't have _any_ `category` elements whose value is `'cat1'` - the values are of the form "cat1 - newline - eight spaces".   You probably need to check `normalize-space(category)` instead of just `category`.

Comment: @BeniBela, I am wondering whether it is a bug or a feature too. Other implementations like Saxon seem to think it is a bug as they treat the `/if ` as a path expression. But I got lost in the XPath 2.0 spec trying to read the expression grammar and the precedence rules.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression looks like correct XPath 2.0 syntax to me, so I don't understand the error message. (What XPath processor are you using?)

However, the semantics are all wrong. You're binding a variable $product which you aren't using. What is the context node at the time? If it is the root element, then the expressions price, cat, name, and id aren't going to return anything, because they require the product element as the context node. Try:

```
/doc/product/(if (price > 20 and cat = 'cat1') then name else id)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple error on your xpath expression, in place of cat, must be category:

```
/doc/product/(if (price > 20 and category='cat1') then name else id)
```

Just that. The expression works fine.